# Add to settings in chrome devtools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a chrome extension that adds a new panel to devtools.

This works as expected, but now looking to add some custom settings. I am hoping to be able to add to the standard chrome devtools settings dialog rather than having to implement a "in panel" settings panel.

I suspect there is no way of doing so after reading through the
[Extending Devtools](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) page and using Google-Fu, I found no mention of the settings dialog or adding my own settings to said dialog.

I know I can create an "in panel" settings panel and it will be easy enough, but I just didn't want to re-invent the wheel if I had no need.

Any information about / or even a confirmation of the lack of ability to add my own settings will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: By custom settings, do you mean an extension that will be part of the menu items (hamburger button)?

Comment: By custom settings, I mean adding to the settings dialog within DevTools. I will update to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to add a new panel into Settings Dialog within DevTools.

However, this sounds as a good suggestion, feel free to file a bug at http://crbug.com/new.